# Plugin set default setting value when it activated

Tags: plugins, settings-api

I have set up my plugin option on admin panel with

```
   /**
     * Register and add settings
     */
    public function page_init()
    {        
        register_setting(
            'my_option_group', // Option group
            'write_here_options', // Option name
            array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'setting_section_id', // ID
            'Set Edit Page', // Title
            array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
            'write-here-setting' // Page
        );  

        add_settings_field(
            "pid_num", 
            "Select Page >>", 
            array( $this, 'wh_select_list' ),  
            "write-here-setting", 
            "setting_section_id"
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'num_of_posts', // ID
            'Number of Posts to show', // Title 
            array( $this, 'num_of_posts_callback' ), // Callback
            'write-here-setting', // Page
            'setting_section_id' // Section           
        ); 

    }
```

So in DB, my plugin setting saved in `wp_options` table under column name `option_name` as `write_here_options` in my case as object.

When people activate the plugin, I want to save default values in the DB for `pid_num => 0` and `num_of_posts => 10`.

How do I make this work??

Comment: rather than save default values, just use default values in your code if the options don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added below code to set default value to DB when plugin is activated.

```
function write_here_activation_actions(){
    do_action( 'wp_writehere_extension_activation' );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'write_here_activation_actions' );
// Set default values here
function write_here_default_options(){
    $default = array(
        'pid_num'     => '0',
        'num_of_posts'   => '10'
    );
    update_option( 'write_here_options', $default );
}
add_action( 'wp_writehere_extension_activation', 'write_here_default_options' );
```

Comment: Issue with this is that if you deactivate the plugin, then turn it back on, all the users customization will be replaced by the defaults.

Comment: @JeremyMuckel I have posted an answer which deals with this particular issue

Comment: Jeremy is correct, but Remzi's solution is wrong in this context.

`$default = array(
  'pid_num'     => '0',
  'num_of_posts'   => '10'
);
update_option( 'write_here_options', $default );`

This IS the code the OP originally needed, they just have not implemented it in a good place.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will certainly use [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) to retrieve the values for your options. `get_option()` accepts a second argument that allows you to specify a default. Use that instead of inserted values into the database unnecessarily.

```
get_option( $option, $default );
```

If you are concerned about third party code, there is there is the [`option_{$option}` filter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/option.php#L116) that you should be able to use to preserve your default even then:

```
116         /**
117          * Filter the value of an existing option.
118          *
119          * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$option`, refers to the option name.
120          *
121          * @since 1.5.0 As 'option_' . $setting
122          * @since 3.0.0
123          *
124          * @param mixed $value Value of the option. If stored serialized, it will be
125          *                     unserialized prior to being returned.
126          */
127         return apply_filters( 'option_' . $option, maybe_unserialize( $value ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually implemented below code to save the default value to DB but I would like to see how's your method will work. I'm not very clear on your answer. How do I save default value without saving them in DB? with your code?

Comment: You don't  save the value to the database at all. `get_option()` will provide the default if nothing is saved to the database.

Comment: I think I got it! `$default = array(
        'pid_num'     => '0',
        'num_of_posts'   => '10'
    );
$no_exists_value = get_option( 'write_here_options', $default );
var_dump( $no_exists_value );` for my case. However, it does not seem like working when I try to retrieve the default value with `$get_nop_setting = get_option('write_here_options');
    $post_pp = $get_nop_setting['num_of_posts'];`

Comment: @Ohsik Your answer doesn't take into account if a user deactivates the plugin, then turns it back on, all the users customization will be replaced by the defaults. I have posted an answer which deals with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use add_option instead of update_option. If you use add_option existing options will not be updated and checks are performed to ensure that you aren’t adding a protected WordPress option.

See [add_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/) and [update_option at developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/)

```
// Activation
function name_plugin_activation(){
    do_action( 'name_plugin_default_options' );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'name_plugin_activation' );


// Set default values here
function name_plugin_default_values(){

    // Form settings
    add_option('name_form_to', 'info@example.com');
    add_option('name_form_subject', 'New');


}
add_action( 'name_plugin_default_options', 'name_plugin_default_values' );
```

Comment: This is wrong in this context. As in the example in the codex, there is one option 'write_here_options' and the settings are stored as an array within that option:

`$options = get_option('write_here_options');
$setting_1 = $options['pid_num'];`

In your example you're just defining multiple options with defaults. It's not the same.